# How to register Singletons of a class with IocManager for different sets of constructor parameters in Aspnet boilerplate

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I have an Aspnet boilerplate C# web application and in a `PreInitialize()` method of a module I have this dependency registration

```
IocManager.Register<IMyProvider, MyConcreteProvider>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

The `MyConcreteProvider` class has a constructor that I use to pass one parameter when I resolve the `IMyProvider` interface. I need to do this way because the behaviour of the `MyConcreteProvider` changes depending on the parameter value passed.

```
using (var providerDisposable = IocResolver.ResolveAsDisposable<IMyProvider>(providerInstance, new
{
  param = "Test"
}))
{
  // Use providerInstance
}
```

It works good but at each instantiation of the `IMyProvider` interface the `MyConcreteProvider` class gets re-created. What I would like to have is a Singleton of the `MyConcreteProvider` based on the `param` parameter value, so that if I instantiate twice the `MyConcreteProvider` class passing both the times the same value "Test" to the `param` parameter, it gets instantiated only once.

So the question is, how to register Singletons of a class with `IocManager` for different values of constructor parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a custom scope based on `param`.

```cs
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    base.PreInitialize();

    IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
        Component.For<IMyProvider>().ImplementedBy<MyConcreteProvider>()
            .LifestyleScoped<MyProviderScopeAccessor>()
    );
}
```

```cs
public class MyProviderScopeAccessor : IScopeAccessor
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILifetimeScope> collection = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILifetimeScope>();

    public ILifetimeScope GetScope(CreationContext context)
    {
        var param = (string)context.AdditionalArguments["param"];
        return collection.GetOrAdd(param, new DefaultLifetimeScope());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var scope in collection)
        {
            scope.Value.Dispose();
        }
        collection.Clear();
    }
}
```

References:

1. https://riptutorial.com/castle-windsor/example/25168/custom-lifestyle---iscopeaccessor
2. https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/implementing-custom-scope.md